# Sharing files when communityId is null

Tags: apex, api, chatter

I'm currently trying to share files on groups where i'm an internal user. My communityId is null

I'm using both of these methods:

> postFeedElement(communityId, feedElement)
>
> postCommentToFeedElement(communityId, feedElementId, comment,
> feedElementFileUpload)

In order to share texts and files on groups. However whenever I login as an internal user and my communityId is null I keep getting this error when I try to post a feed

> invalid contentDocumentId[id]

Whenever I try to post a file on a comment I get

> You can't share a file from a different community.

As if I were sending a different communityId when I know it's null.

Am I doing something wrong? Whenever I'm in some other community with an Id, this works fine.

Update: I know where the problem lies but i don't know if i can control it. The problem occurs when i login as an internal user inside a community. When this happens the

> forcetk.Client()

which i'm using right now to create the record by using the "createBlob" method. I'm setting up the

> "networkId"

value to null but when it finishes uploading i can see that the networkId value is the same as the communityId even though im not in a community. Any advice on this bug on the forcetk library would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Both CollaborationGroup and ContentVersion object has column networkId.
In org having communities enabled, these columns networkId = null for internal CollaborationGroup and ContentVersion records
Please check CollaborationGroup.networkId and ContentVersion.networkId record used.

Comment: I understand what's happening now. What's happening is that even though im setting my networkId to be null, since my instanceURL is from a community, salesforce is clearly setting the networkId to the communityId of the instanceURL. That's why networkId is saved with a value even though neither me or the forcetk library sets a value for the networkId.